# Convert a "Complex" HTML Table to JSON

Tags: json, node.js

So the last few days i have been struggling to find a working solution to this problem.(NodeJS)

I already tried things like cheerio html tables etc but most of them dont work cause they dont handle the rowspans etc.

Basically i need a HTML table like this :

```
<table class="k" border-width="3">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th width="50">
            XXXXXX </th>
        <th width="50">
            YYYY</th>
        <th width="50">
            </th>
        <th width="50">
            ZZZZZZZZ</th>
        <th width="50">
            QQQQ</th>
        <th width="50">
            LLLL</th>
        <th width="150">
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="k">
        <th rowspan="11" class="k">
            11</th>
        <td>
            Data</td>
        <td>
            1</td>
        <td>
            Data2</td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            Data3</td>
        <td>
            Data4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
           Data5</td>
        <td>
            2</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            Data6</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;Data7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;Data8</td>
        <td>
            2</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;Data10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;Foo</td>
        <td>
            3</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;Foo</td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;Foo</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;Foo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;Foo</td>
        <td>
            3</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;Foo</td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;Foo</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;Foo</td>
        <td>
            4</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;Foo</td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;Foo</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;Foo</td>
        <td>
            4</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;Foo</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

to convert to something like this:

```
{
"XXXXXX": "11",
"YYYY": "Data",
"SSS": "1",
"ZZZZZZZZ": "Data2",
"QQQQ": "",
"LLLL": "Data3",
"Data4": ""}
```

for each row in the table

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this in NodeJS is by using the npm module [html-table-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-table-to-json).

```
const HtmlTableToJson = require('html-table-to-json');
const html = '' # Paste your HTML table

const jsonTables = new HtmlTableToJson(html);

console.log(jsonTables['results']);
```

Comment: Already tried,doesn't really work , everything is really messed up

Comment: How doesn't it really work? Is the data in the wing structure?

Comment: Its not in the right structure at all. Most of the node modules for tables dont handle the "rowspans". But i think i found a solution with cheerio-tableparser.